# Return all child categories using mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table named 'category' as like in the bellow image .it have a parent_id field refers to the parent category id and we can add n number child category for each category.There is more than one category like 'A-1'

[image]

I need to write a query to return the category and all of its subcategories from the table for a given category id.so it will need to select all of its child category and child of that child category up to getting all of its child's.for this i have written the bellow query.

```
select @pv:=id as category_id, name, parent_id from category
join (select @pv:=1)tmp where parent_id=@pv
```

And it returns only 3 rows like as follows

[image]

But here we ca see that all of the categories in this list is a child of A-1.but it is not returning all of them.how can i fix this?

Comment: You have to reconsider the storage model and there's no other easy way around that. MySQL supports neither recursion nor other window functions in any way. Therefore your current pattern of tree storage ("adjacency tree") won't work for your task. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: MySQL does support recursion, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive

Comment: @JimmyB ok, latest one does. Then it boils down to the specific version

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the children have an id greater than the parent. Considering that, can you change your query as below.

```
select @pv:=id as category_id, name, parent_id from category
where parent_id >@pv
```

Comment: There is large number of category,not a single one

Comment: You said, "for a given category". Hence the above solution. Is it like "parent_id in (1,2,3)"? If so why wouldn't you use ORDER BY id, parent_id?

Comment: This query return empty result

Comment: Did you try this? select id, name, parent_id from category
ORDER BY id, parent_id

Comment: Yes,i tried.but the logic is not correct i think

Comment: The query cannot return empty result, if the table is not empty as there is no where clause to filter results. Ideally it should pull all rows from the table.